# How do I do this "order by" in Django, if I have foreign keys?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

Suppose my model is this:

```
class Ego(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

As you can see, this table has 2 columns, and they're both foreign keys.
How do I "order by" User.first_name?

Is this it? But it doesn't look like it.

```
Ego.objects.all().order_by("User.first_name")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I did this:

```
Ego.objects.all().select_related.order_by("auth_user.first_name")
```

Comment: What SQL does that generate? Out of interest, does `Ego.objects.all().order_by("user__first_name")` work?